# Importing CSV having Duplicate Column names with SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc, import-csv

I have 3 csv files located in different network folders. The network folders/sub-folders may have spaces in them. I want to join these 3 csv files to create a single ADO Recordset containing required columns.

**Test1.csv** (I have excluded unnecessary columns from all csv's)

```
T1Id  | Gpos | lbl
-----------------------
1001  |  0   | Innovate
1002  |  1   | Buys
1003  |  2   | Sales
1004  |  3   | Forecasts
1005  |  4   | Usage
1006  |  5   | Forum
```

**Test2.csv:** (I have excluded unnecessary columns from all csv's)

```
T2Id |  T1Id |  Apos | tval
-----------------------------------
382  |  1001 |  1   | my life my rules.
203  |  1001 |  2   | earth wind rain and fire.
658  |  1002 |  1   | wealth power blood desire.
200  |  1003 |  1   | one good to live for.
301  |  1003 |  2   | before we die.
439  |  1004 |  1   | one taste to glory
795  |  1004 |  2   | one mouthful of sky.
494  |  1004 |  3   | some other text.
```

**Test3.csv:** (I have excluded unnecessary columns from all csv's)

```
(blank)  Aggregate (blank) Aggregate  149_SG_Bryl_Cream   891_SG_Myo__Sky_Blue_Dress
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
X0.1     0.422300          0.424658    0.458014          0.434639
X0.2     0.318628          0.345475    0.334548          0.333675
X0.3     0.274694          0.274643    0.243424          0.286865
X0.4     0.294568          0.346758    0.276552          0.366648
X1.1     0.565734          0.293436    0.283564          0.235366
X1.2     0.286657          0.755456    0.283233          0.310544
X2.1     0.234643          0.245459    0.245434          0.343423
X2.2     0.343645          0.455659    0.343282          0.334343
X2.3     0.234643          0.245459    0.245434          0.343423
```

As you can see, Test3.csv has 4 issues:

1. It has Columns with Blank headers, but containing data e.g. `X0.1`.
2. It has Columns with Blank headers, but with `no data`.
3. It has 2 `Aggregate` columns with same names.
4. It has `SG` columns (many) that i need to extract `only the part starting from 'SG'.`

**Requirements**

1. `Test1` & `Test2` CSVs need to be joined on `T1Id`.
2. Only the `lbl` and `tval` columns from these file need ot be kept.
3. The `Apos` and `Gpos` will be used to join 2 columns created from the 1st blank Header column (containing values like `X0.1`) in `Test3.csv` file.

**Code:**

```vb
Sub Doit(cFiles As Collection)
        
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim strSQL1$, TempSG$,sFullDirectory$
    
    sFullDirectory = `\\xxx.xxx.xxx\client name`\
    
    strFF1 = "Test1.csv"
    strFF2 = "Test2.csv"
    strFF3 = "Test3.csv"
   
    ' Test1.csv Path: `\\xxx.xxx.xxx\client name\XYZ\sub-folder1 name`\
    strF1 = cFiles(strFF1) 

    ' Test1.csv Path: `\\xxx.xxx.xxx\client name\ABC\sub-folder2 name`\
    strF2 = cFiles(strFF2)

    ' Test1.csv Path: `\\xxx.xxx.xxx\client name\DEF\GHI\sub-folder1 name`\
    strF3 = cFiles(strFF3)

    Set oCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set oRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    strCon = "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq=" & sFullDirectory & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;HDR=Yes;"
    
    ' Select TOP 1 row with headers from `Test3.csv`
    strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM " & strF3 & strFF3
    oCon.Open strCon
    Set oRs = oCon.Execute(strSQL)
    
    i = 1
    strSQL = "SELECT "

    For Each Fld In oRs.Fields
        Select Case True
            Case Is = Fld.Name = "NoName"  'Blank header columns
                If Fld.Value <> vbNullString Then
                    strSQL = strSQL & " CLng(Replace(Left(" & Fld.Name & ", InStr(" & Fld.Name & ", '.') - 1), 'X', ''))" & " AS [gval],"
                    strSQL = strSQL & " CLng(Right(" & Fld.Name & ", Len(" & Fld.Name & ") - InStr(" & Fld.Name & ", '.')))" & " AS [pos],"
                Else
                ' Do nothing here
                End If
            Case Is = Fld.Name = "Aggregate"
                strSQL = strSQL & " CDbl([" & Fld.Name & "]) AS [Aggregate " & i & "],"
                i = i + 1
            Case Is = InStr(1, Fld.Name, "SG") > 0
                TempSG = Trim(Mid(Fld.Name, InStr(1, Fld.Name, "SG"), Len(Fld.Name)))
                strSQL = strSQL & " CDbl([" & Fld.Name & "]) AS [" & TempSG & "], "
        End Select
    Next Fld
    
    If Right(Trim(strSQL), 1) = "," Then strSQL = Left(Trim(strSQL), Len(Trim(strSQL)) - 1)
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM " & strF3 & strFF3
    strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE ((NoName) <> 'Base Sizes')"
    
    oRs.Close
    
    ' This `strSQL1` will be used to join `strSQL`.
    strSQL1 = "SELECT  G.[lbl], A.[tval], Q.*"
    strSQL1 = strSQL1 & " FROM "
    strSQL1 = strSQL1 & " (SELECT G.[Gpos], A.[Apos], G.[lbl], A.[tval] FROM " & strF1 & strFF1 & "  G," & strF2 & strFF2 & "  A WHERE G.[T1Id] = A.[T1Id])  T, (" & strSQL & ")  Q "
    strSQL1 = strSQL1 & " WHERE (CLng(T.[G].[Gpos]) = CLng(Q.[gval])) AND (CLng(T.[A].[Apos]) = CLng(Q.[pos]))"
    strSQL1 = strSQL1 & " ORDER BY CLng(Q.[gval]), CDbl(Q.[Aggregate 1]) DESC, G.[lbl];"
    
    'CREATE RECORDSET FROM SQL STRING
    Set oRs = oCon.Execute(strSQL1)
    
ExitSub:
    oRs.Close
    oCon.Close
    Set oRs = Nothing
    Set oCon = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "An Error occurred!"
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    Resume ExitSub

End Sub
```

After Splitting the Test3.csv table would like this:

```
gval   pos    (blank)  Aggregate (blank) Aggregate  149_SG_Bryl_Cream   891_SG_Myo__Sky_Blue_Dress
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0      1     0.422300          0.424658    0.458014          0.434639
0      2     0.318628          0.345475    0.334548          0.333675
0      3     0.274694          0.274643    0.243424          0.286865
0      4     0.294568          0.346758    0.276552          0.366648
1      1     0.565734          0.293436    0.283564          0.235366
1      2     0.286657          0.755456    0.283233          0.310544
2      1     0.234643          0.245459    0.245434          0.343423
2      2     0.343645          0.455659    0.343282          0.334343
2      3     0.234643          0.245459    0.245434          0.343423
```

**Final Table:** (short example)

```
lbl       txval                     gval    pos  Aggregate 1       Aggregate 2   SG_Bryl_Cream    SG_Myo__Sky_Blue_Dress
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Innovate  My life my rules.          0      1    0.422300          0.424658    0.458014          0.434639
Innovate  earth wind rain and fire.  0      2    0.318628          0.345475    0.334548          0.333675
Buys      my life my rules.          1      1    0.565734          0.293436    0.283564          0.235366
Buys      earth wind rain and fire.  1      2    0.286657          0.755456    0.283233          0.310544
Sales     my life my rules.          2      1    0.234643          0.245459    0.245434          0.343423
Sales     earth wind rain and fire.  2      2    0.343645          0.455659    0.343282          0.334343
Sales     Some other text.           2      3    0.234643          0.245459    0.245434          0.343423
...
```

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to pickup both duplicate `Aggregate` columns via SQL?
2. Is there a way to Select only `SG` columns from `Q` ie. `Test3.csv` via SQL?

**e.g.**

```vb
strSQL1 = "SELECT  G.[lbl], A.[tval], Q.* "
```

instead:

```
strSQL1 = "SELECT  G.[lbl], A.[tval], Q.* LIKE 'SG' "
```

Comment: I know you are not asking advice on this, but I am sure you could give better names to both Average Columns, even if you get the problem sorted this way, this is recipe for disaster... They could be called whatever they are the average of... Average_Temp or Average_Weight, whatever...

Comment: @AndrasDorko, yes they represent some different weights, but i need to pull them first. Right now, i am helpless as only the 1st Average column gets pulled in twice...though i can see in the Watch window on looping on the Fld.Name, that the 2nd column gets selected the 2nd time.

Comment: Have you tried a `select into` then correcting the resultant table, or using some of the other functions etc of ADO, if you're using that, cant see how the recordset is populated, but there are things like `.openschema` to inspect maybe, not sure how you're accessing, so a bit of a finger in the air.  Or in the connection string `HDR=Yes` could be your solution, leave the fields as is, unless if start "Field"?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, I am using `ODBC Microsoft Access Text Driver` with `HDR=YES` in `EXCEL VBA`. I cannot dump into a `resultant table` as i am creating a `Recordset` on the fly.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning then please?  Where is the data to be going?  Can it not be treated as a text file as in normal opening?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav i am not familiar with `.openschema`. Is there a way to know how duplicate Columns can be referenced individually in SQL with it?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav for automated Pivot Charts and Pivot Tables. Via VBA code, i am creating an SQL string that joins multiple csv files to pull different columns and create a single recordset. Hope this makes things clear.

Answer (score 2):

Consider running pure SQL by querying the CSV file directly with needed column aliases:

```sql
SELECT t.Food, t.Bev, t.Meds, t.[Average], t.Midpoint, t.Average AS [OtherAverage]
FROM [text;database=C:\Folder\To\CSV With Spaces].[my File.csv] AS t;
```

Additionally, query can be integrated into action queries:

Make-Table Query

```sql
SELECT t.Food, t.Bev, t.Meds, t.[Average], t.Midpoint, t.Average AS [OtherAverage]
INTO [myNewtable]
FROM [text;database=C:\Folder\To\CSV With Spaces].[my File.csv] AS t;
```

Append Query

```sql
INSERT INTO myFinalTable (Food, Bev, Meds, Average, Midpoint, OtherAverage)
SELECT t.Food, t.Bev, t.Meds, t.Average, t.Midpoint, t.Average AS [OtherAverage]
FROM [text;database=C:\Folder\To\CSV With Spaces].[my File.csv] AS t;
```

---

To run with ADO in VBA, use the Jet/ACE SQL engine either with Excel or Access ODBC driver where workbook or database file source does not matter since you remotely connect to CSV:

```vb
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' EXCEL DRIVER
conn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
            & "DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";"
rst.Open "SELECT t.Food, t.Bev, t.Meds, t.[Average], t.Midpoint, t.Average AS [OtherAverage] " _
            & " FROM [text;database=C:\Folder\To\CSV With Spaces].[my File.csv] AS t", conn 

' ACCESS DRIVER
conn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" _
            & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Any\Database.accdb"
rst.Open "SELECT t.Food, t.Bev, t.Meds, t.[Average], t.Midpoint, t.Average AS [OtherAverage] " _
            & " FROM [text;database=C:\Folder\To\CSV With Spaces].[my File.csv] AS t", conn
```

Using the Access ODBC text driver

```sql
Set oCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

sFullDirectory = "C:\Folder\To\CSV With Spaces"

strCon = "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);" _
           & "Dbq=" & sFullDirectory & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;HDR=Yes;"
strSQL = "SELECT t.Food, t.Bev, t.Meds, t.[Average], t.Midpoint, t.Average AS [OtherAverage] " _
            & " FROM [my File.csv] AS t"

oCon.Open strCon
Set oRs = oCon.Execute(strSQL)
```

Comment: I am using the `MICROSOFT ACCESS TEXT DRIVER` because the file paths contain spaces in the sub-folders. I am not able to work with JET or ACE because of this reason.

Comment: Yes, I using backticks with the Access driver, which somehow don't work with ACE. BTW, I am using Excel 2016 pro.

Comment: modified the post including the entire code. Also, included the other post question here to save time.

Comment: Wow! This is a radically different question now. Will need to delete my answer here. Fundamentally, you should not use SQL which relies on structured, relational data not flat files of varying content. SQL on CSV is a convenience tool. Consider data analytics tools (Python Pandas, R, Julia, SAS, Stata, SPSS) which can easily read in CSVs, split and clean up headers, and merge data sets or run loops in Excel to clean up the CSVs.

Comment: Hi @Parfait, could you update your answer for the various drivers, to reflect a join between 2 files viz., `File1.csv` & `File2.csv` ? Currently, i am getting an error `Syntax error in FROM clause` when i am trying to join 2 csv files.

Comment: Please show your attempted SQL. Make sure you bracket the file names `[...]`.

Comment: here is the post where i have put the SQL and issue. Could you help me with it? I tried using your given suggestions with the various drivers, but not working. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917099/excel-vba-microsoftodbc-text-driver-record-is-too-large`