# Excel VBA - [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Record is too Large

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, transform, adodb

I am joining 2 csv files using a `Transform` (Pivoting) query with `Microsoft Access Text Driver (ADODB)` in Excel 2016 using VBA. Both csv files are small i.e. 1 is not more than 10 rows and the other may be not more than 20 rows. The `Transform` query works fine with most csv files. I am only picking up 1 or 2 columns from both the joining files - even though the columns are just 10-15 columns.

However, recently with one of the joining files having 60 rows, i started getting an error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Record is too Large.

**Observations:**

- I saw that if i tried reducing the number of rows in one of the files from 60 rows to 30 rows, it works!
- If i run the same query in `MSAccess`, it works fine even with one of the files having 60 rows.
- I tried replicating scenario by choosing the `Microsoft Access Text Driver` and importing the 2 csv files in `MSQuery`, then running the `Transform query`, but got the same `Record is too Large` error.
- I tried changing the ODBC driver connection string to `SQL ACE Engine`, but still the same.
- Initially i thought it could be that the filepath length may be > 255 characters, but that is not the case. It is within the range.
- Initially i thought it could be spaces in the filepath, but i have found a solution of enclosing filepath in `back-ticks`, which handles filepaths with spaces, if using the `Microsoft Access Text Driver` to join files.
- Someone suggested to convert the `TextValue` field IN `File2.csv` containing long text (not greater than 80-100 characters) as a `MEMO field`. I am not sure how to convert it in a `SELECT TRANSFORM Query`.

Here is a snapshot of the SQL Query & VBA code.

`` TRANSFORM FIRST(A.[textValue]) AS TextValue  SELECT clng(G.[position]) AS [G-Value], 1 AS Theme,COUNT(clng(A.[position])) AS Var, G.[label] AS [Attribute Name] FROM `C:\ABC\DEF GHI\JKL MNO PQR\TEST 1\SUBTEST 1\2019\DOIT 1\1-2`\File1.csv AS G,`C:\ABC\DEF GHI\JKL MNO PQR\TEST 2\SUBTEST 2\2019\DOIT 2\1-2`\File2.csv AS A WHERE G.[geneid] = A.[geneid] GROUP BY clng(G.[position]),G.[label] ORDER BY clng(A.[position]) Asc PIVOT clng(A.[position]) ``

The connection string i am using is:

```
Set oCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strCon = "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);DriverId=27;Dbq=" & sFullDirectory & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;FIL=text"

With oCon
    .cursorlocation = adUseClient
    .connectionstring = strCon
    .Open
End With

Set oRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With oRs
    .cursortype = adOpenStatic
    .locktype = adLockBatchOptimistic
    .activeconnection = oCon
    .Open (strSQL)    '----> Error: Record is too Large.
End With
```

**Questions:**

How do i resolve this issue without revamping much of my code (I am using other `Select-Join` queries that depend on the Microsoft Access Text Driver)?

Is there a way to make the ADO query engine recognize the `TextValue` column as a `Memo field` in the `TRANSFORM-SELECT` Query itself? I don't want to create a temporary table using (MAKE or INSERT INTO) to change the data type.
e.g. TRANSFORM CMemo( FIRST(A.[textValue]) ) AS TextValue??

**[File1.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MCPwSOfAlszNBKnwIVNCCH_6mWQ6EDhz2Y-4YxsIWm8) (1 row only)**

[image: File1.csv]

**[File2.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xGuTmMr9QoGI9hHr1iyI_NPwP_vhMsYuMdhTj8MtJgs) (60 rows)**

[image: File2.csv]

Comment: @parfait, can i look forward to your valuable advice on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Has anyone got a solution to this issue?